# MySql query formatting error

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Php/MySQL and having difficulty to run a MySQL query:

```
<?php $connection=require_once("../connection.php");?>
<?php
$query1='SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="{{dbName}}"';

$res=mysqli_query($connection, $query1);
echo $query1. '<br/>';

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    echo $row['TABLE_NAME']. "</br>";
}
?>
```

This query takes the name of the database & shows its tables.

I'm using `ui-router` for routing, at this particular state the name of the db is passed as a parameter that is `"dbName"`. At `"echo $query1"`, it is confirmed that the query is formulated as it should but is not retrieving anything. However, it works fine when specifying the database name directly to the query.

Here is the angularJs code for $stateProvider:

```
var mainModule=angular.module("mainModule", ['ui.router'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/show_databases');
        $stateProvider
            .state('show_databases',{
                url: '/show_databases',
                templateUrl: "templates/show_databases.php"
            })
            .state('show_databases.tables',{
                url: '/show_tables/:db',
                templateUrl: "templates/show_tables.php",
                controller: "dbCtrl"
            })
    })
    .controller("dbCtrl", function($scope, $state, $stateParams){
        $scope.dbName=$stateParams.db;
    });
```

Comment: You can't just mix and match Server and client side as you want.

Comment: Angular isn't going to touch your `dbName`, that's not how it works, you have to use $http and send an http request to a given URL, that does the query.

Comment: like I said, when I check the query it is giving me the correct string.

Comment: Yeah, but that's because "echo" sends it to the Client.

Comment: @Saharcasm, show your current UI Router's `$stateParams` object which relates to intended php page

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest added it to the question